# How to process two python dataframe efficiently?

Tags: python

I have two dataframes, one of which is composed of string separated by spaces.
I want to take out the two separately for calculation. At present, the loop method is used, but when the  data is large, it will take a long time to get results.
Is there a more efficient way?

df

| num | test |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a dog is |
| 2 | the sky is blue |

df1

| word |
| --- |
| a |
| is |
| blue |

output

| word | num | sscore |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 123 |
| is | 1 | 23 |
| blue | 1 | 35 |
| a | 2 | 33 |
| is | 2 | 21 |
| blue | 2 | 85 |

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame()

for i in trange(len(df)):
    df1['num'] = df['num'].iloc[i]
    df1['rsscore'] = 0

    tsplit = df['text'][i].split()
    for j in range(len(tsplit)):        
        wd = tsplit[j]

        for t in range(len(df1)):
            lwd = df1['word'].iloc[t]
                
            try:
               sscore = model.wv.similarity(lwd, wd)
            except KeyError:
               pass
                
            df1['rsscore'].iloc[t] += sscore
                     
      df2 = df2.append(df1, ignore_index = True)
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t make it clear before. It is to split the 'test' column in df dataframe into each word. Then calculate with the 'word' column of row in df1. In this way, I wonder if there is an efficient method for each calculation?

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"num": [1, "s"], "test": ["a dog is", "the sky blue"]})
  num          test
0   1      a dog is
1   s  the sky blue
>>> df['test'] = df['test'].str.split()
  num              test
0   1      [a, dog, is]
1   s  [the, sky, blue]
>>> df2 = df.explode('test')
  num  test
0   1     a
0   1   dog
0   1    is
1   s   the
1   s   sky
1   s  blue
```

You can then use e.g. `apply` to run your similarity/... on each word; I just have this bogus metric of "length times 8":

```
>>> df2['rsscore'] = df2['test'].apply(lambda x: len(x) * 8)
  num  test  rsscore
0   1     a        8
0   1   dog       24
0   1    is       16
1   s   the       24
1   s   sky       24
1   s  blue       32
```

It might be worth to annotate your `similarity(x, y)` function with e.g. the `lru_cache` decorator if you expect there to be many of the same word.